# How to add two columns with the same names from different Tables

Tags: powerpivot

How to add two cloumns with the same name from different tables.  It needs to be dymanic, because i have columns based on months. Below is the sample data. which i would use to calculate the moving 12 month average for attrition.

```
Transferout    Oct'11   Nov'11
3310ED      
3310FL      
3310HD      1
3310PZ      
3310RC       
3310SH      
3310SM      1 

Terinations Oct'11  Nov'11
3310ED      
3310FL      
3310HD      1 
3310PZ      1 
3310RC
```

So according to the column name and dept id in the row filed the above two tables needs to be added and later divided by the head count of the respective dept ids using the same column headings in a diff table

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the [LOOKUPVALUE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx) function or the [RELATED](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634202.aspx) function (if the tables are related).